# remote accessfrom windows 7 to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7

I am trying to access remotely to Ubuntu machine from windows 7 device. I successfully enabled RDP in linux machine and was able to access it remotely using the default remote desktop connection in windows. However, i received a very bad color and resolution.

I tried to edit display at linux device but received  "RANDR extension is too old (must be at least 1.2)" error message.

Is there any approach to enhance the color display or resolution?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: If you want to access a Linux box from a Windows box why don't you just use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use "team viewer". It's a program that can be installed in Ubuntu I personally have it... and it's crossed platform between Windows, Mac's and Android/ apple devices... No  hassle between connection and all it requires is a password to access from one system to another.

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx